# nsupdate works directly but not via openvpn

Tags: networking, openvpn, bind, port, nsupdate

I can update my bind server with nsupdate when I start my script directly from the terminal. However when I start the script it from inside openvpn then I get a time out error:
`Communication with 1xx.xxx.x.x#53 failed: timed out`.

The key is found.

The port 53 is open for udp and tcp. In my named.conf I tried the option `listen-on port 53 { any; };`.

I start it from terminal with `./nsupdate-both.sh`.
From inside OPENVPN I tried both the up and the ipchange hooks.
Openvpn client config:

```
script-security 2
ipchange /etc/openvpn/nsupdate-both.sh ;
```

Anyone has an idea why its working directly from terminal, but not from openvpn?

Answer (score 1):

Both the `ipchange` and the `up` hooks are run before any routes pulled from the server. Any script which runs in those hooks and tries to access a VPN resource will fail because the routing is not set up yet.

Use the `route-up` hook, that runs after the routes are applied, and the VPN resources are available.

Comment: Unfortunalety that `route-up` hook also returns the same error - connection timed out.
Maybe Openvpn does not have the right to send the update to port 53?